# How can I post from a form to a URL and get a JSON back from it using Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a post request using a form and wanting the answer to be a JSON with the data that the user entered in the form.

This is my index.pug file:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title HPI
  body
    h1 Formulario HPI
    #container
      form(action="/formulario" method="post")
       label(for='nodoHpi') Nodo Hpi
       input#nodoHpi(name='nodoHpi', type='text')
       br
       br
       label(for='nombreIndice') Nombre Indice
       input#nombreIndice(name='nombreIndice', type='text')
       br
       br
       label(for='valorIndice') Valor Indice
       input#valorIndice(name='valorIndice', type='text')
       br
       br
       button(type="submit") SEND
```

I really don't know how to do this ...

What I need is that when the user enters the info in the 3 inputs provided, the data posts to a JSON that is in a different URL

**"172.**.20.**:12***/search"**

Then I need that JSON rendered back and showned in my HTML.

This is the JSON example:

```
{
    "token": "1",
    "query": [{
        "index": "ALTC.MC_ROBERTS",
        "terms": [{
            "name": "INDEXTEXT01T",
            "value": "3044071*",
            "operator": "like"
        }],
        "results": {
            "count": 5000,
            "sort": [{
                "name": "ISSUE_DATE",
                "order": "descending"
            }],
            "fields": []
        }
    }]
}
```

There are 3 values in the JSON that need to be variable and those are the 3 input's I want the user to enter in the index.pug file.

These are:

**ALTC.MC_ROBERTS**

**INDEXTEXT01T**

**3044071**

Finally this is my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const hostname = '172.19.20.10:12530/search';
const port = '3000';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var headersOpt = {  
    "content-type": "application/json",
};

request.post(
        {
        method:'post',
        url:'http://172.19.20.10:12530/search', 
        form: {nombreIndice:'hello',valorIndice:25, nodoHpi: 'nodo'}, 
        headers: headersOpt,
        json: true,
    }, function (error, response, body) {  
        //Print the Response
        console.log(body);  
}); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index');
});

app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    res.render('formulario', {prueba: req.body.nodoHpi});
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("The server is listening in localhost: 3000");
});
```

Example:

If the user enters 2, John and Xmas in the index.pug form I need that form to do a Post request to this URL "172..20.:12*/search"**, and then get back the JSON in a different .pug file.

Any ideas would help a lot sience I'm stuck and new to Express.

Best regards to everyone !

Comment: Are you building the server at 172.19.20.10:12530/search

Comment: no, I'm building the server in localHost, I guess !

Comment: you will have to have access to the server at http://172.19.20.10:12530 to be able to specify the kind of response you want

Comment: Okey, that helps a loottt ! Is it okey what I'm doing with my code apart from the server ?